# Google Tag Manager variables passed as [Object object]

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am using GTM and am trying to submit a purchase event however both custom_map and items are sent and reported as [Object object].

I have been following these official docs from google:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/ecommerce
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

Here is my code:

```js
gtag('config', 'GTM-ID', {
    custom_map: {
        dimension1: 'tenant_name',
        dimension2: 'office_id'
    }
});

gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    transaction_id: 'string',
    value: 12345,
    currency: 'string',
    tenant_name: 'string',
    office_id: 'string',
    items: [
        {
            id: 'string',
            name: 'string',
            price: 12345,
            quantity: 5
        }
    ]
});
```

Of course the data in the example is dummy data, however the structure and data types are exactly the same. Looking at the request payload, both custom_map and items are encoded as [Object object].

The following is the request payload:

```
en=purchase&_et=6&ep.custom_map=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&ep.transaction_id=string&epn.value=12346&ep.tenant_name=string&ep.office_id=string&ep.items=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&cu=string
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that supposed to be the actual code? You get `[Object object]` as a result when arbitrary objects are forced into a string context, but that’s not the case in what you have shown.

Comment: You are sending an object representation to the dataLayer, without knowing which method/variable you are calling it's hard to say.

Comment: It is particularly weird because I have been following their docs. I understand the underlying reason to why it happens (an object being cast to string) although I have no clue to why the implementation doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Can you link to the site of where you have your gtag code implemented? the parameters in your payload doesn't match what they should be when using gtag.js and ecommerce.

Comment: Hi @XTOTHEL, thanks for the comment. The project is private therefore I'm not able to provide a link. Your mention on the payload is intriguing - could you expand/pinpoint to where it is wrong?